# how to redirect to a page with pk

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

i have this function

```
def edit_profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/profile')
else:
    form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'store/edit_profile.html', args)
```

i want it to redirect to this function

```
def view_profile(request, pk):
 data = cartData(request)
cartItems = data['cartItems']
shippingAddress = ShippingAddress.objects.get(id=pk)
# orderItem = OrderItem.objects.get(id=pk)

args = {'user': request.user, 'cartItems': cartItems, 'shippingAddress': shippingAddress}  # 'orderItem': orderItem
return render(request, 'store/profile.html', args)
```

the urls

```
path('profile/<str:pk>/', views.view_profile, name="view_profile"),
path('profile/edit', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
```

i want the first function to redirect to the second but i got 'Page not found'
i know the problem with the pk. so i want it to redirect to **profile/id.** is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass it as parameter:

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('view_profile', pk=request.user.pk)
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'store/edit_profile.html', args)
```

You might want to change the `pk` to an [`int` path converter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters):

```
path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.view_profile, name="view_profile"),
path('profile/edit/', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
```

This will then only trigger the view in case a sequence of digits is filled in for the `pk`.